# RegEx for extracting multiple words in a passage using Tableau

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I have a passage and I need to extract a couple of words from it in tableau. The passage is given below:

> This looks like a suspicious account. Please look at the details
>   below. Name: John Mathew    Email:john.mathew@abc.com   Phone:+1
>   111-111-1111  Department: abc
>
> For more enquiries contact: ----

Name, email, phone and the department are in the same line separated by blank spaces. I used the below regex and it works well for the department alone:

```
regexp_extract([CASE DESCRIPTION],'Department : (.+)')
```

When I apply this one name, I get:

> Name: John Mathew    Email:john.mathew@abc.com   Phone:+1 111-111-1111
>   Department: abc

instead of just the name. The same happens with email.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You can use a regex at the data visualization stage for all kinds of useful things, but if you have many complex, messy text fields with several kinds of information you want to attempt to extract, you should also consider adding an information extraction stage in your pipeline to extract structure prior to visualization. At least when you move from a prototyping concept towards a production system. There are alot of Python libraries in this space for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the issue is that your regex just has '(.+)' as its capture group, which basically means "everything" (after the specified string).  Since the fields are all on one line, everything after "name" includes the email, phone, and department.  (The regex works with department because it's the last thing on the line.)
So, to make it work right, you need to give your regex something other than the end of the line to stop on.  To capture just the name, you need to stop before the Email tag, and so on down the list.  Something like

```
Name = regexp_extract([CASE_DESCRIPTION],'Name: (.+) Email:')  
email = regexp_extract([CASE_DESCRIPTION],'Email: (.+) Phone:')
phone = regexp_extract([CASE_DESCRIPTION],'Phone: (.+) Department:')
department = regexp_extract([CASE_DESCRIPTION],'Department: (.+)')
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted it. Thanks a lot Hellion :)